# Python xml.dom and bad XML

Tags: python, xml, dom, expat-parser

I'm trying to extract some data from various HTML pages using a python program. Unfortunately, some of these pages contain user-entered data which occasionally has "slight" errors - namely tag mismatching.

Is there a good way to have python's xml.dom try to correct errors or something of the sort? Alternatively, is there a better way to extract data from HTML pages which may contain errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [HTML Tidy](http://utidylib.berlios.de/) to clean up, or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse. Could be that you have to save the result to a temp file, but it should work.

Cheers,

Comment: Beautiful Soup is not that great.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use BeautifulSoup for such tasks but now I have shifted to **HTML5lib** (http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) which works well in many cases where BeautifulSoup fails

other alternative is to use "**Element Soup**" (http://effbot.org/zone/element-soup.htm) which is a wrapper for Beautiful Soup using ElementTree

Answer (score 0):

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) does a decent job at parsing invalid HTML.

According to their documentation [Beautiful Soup](http://codespeak.net/lxml/elementsoup.html) and [html5lib](http://codespeak.net/lxml/html5parser.html) sometimes perform better depending on the input. With lxml you can choose which parser to use, and access them via an unified API.

Answer (score 0):

If jython is acceptable to you, tagsoup is very good at parsing junk - if it is, I found the jdom libraries far easier to use than other xml alternatives.

This is a snippet from a demo mockup to do with screen scraping from tfl's journey planner:

```
 private Document getRoutePage(HashMap params) throws Exception {
        String uri = "http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/bcl/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2";
        HttpWrapper hw = new HttpWrapper();
        String page = hw.urlEncPost(uri, params);
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
        Reader pageReader = new StringReader(page);
        return builder.build(pageReader);
    }
```